# Make indexable IList

Tags: c#, list, indexing

```
        IMS_ProductController pc = new IMS_ProductController();
        IList<IMS_Product>  newrec= new List<IMS_Product>();
        newrec.Add(new IMS_Product()
        {
            Name = "Bobo",
            Description = "Some desc",
            Url = "http",
            ProductInfoUrl = "http"
        })
        IMS_Product ip = new IMS_Product();
        IEnumerator<IMS_Product> myprod = newrec.GetEnumerator();
        myprod.MoveNext();
        foreach (var prop in ip.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(prop.Name); //this works. Returns "Name","Description","URL","ProductInfoURL"
            Console.WriteLine(myprod.Current.Name); //This works. Returns "Bobo" each time
            Console.WriteLine(myprod.Current[prop.Name]); //this does NOT work. IList is not indexable. 
        }
```

How do I make line 3 in the foreach work? What do I have to cast as what to make an indexable list/array/whatever?

Thank you!
Chris

Comment: What are you trying to do in the 3rd line?

Comment: Why are you iterating the list manually versus using a `foreach` on the list itself?

Comment: I'm trying to return "Bobo" -- the value of "Name" in my class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to use the [GetValue method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194385%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to do something like this:

```
//Loop through objects
foreach(IMS_Product prod in newrec) 
{
    //Loop through properties
    foreach (var prop in typeof(IMS_Product).GetProperties()) 
    {
         //Print property name
         Console.WriteLine(prop.Name);

         //Print property value
         Console.WriteLine(prop.GetValue(prod));
    }
}
```

Comment: That generates errors because myprod is not indexable,

Comment: @Chris, I am not really sure what you mean. `prod` is just a loop variable here. Did you test this code?

Comment: and...that did it. Ok. I think I even understand that now. Wow. This has been hours of fun. Thank you much. I appreciate this.

Comment: I am glad I could help